# Does it matter if a Java 6 artifact gets compiled with Java 6, 7 or 8?

Tags: java, compilation, compatibility

I have configured a continuous integration tool (Travis CI) to run on every commit I make, it builds my Java 6 project on the following JDK's:

- Oracle JDK 8
- Oracle JDK 7
- Open JDK 7
- Open JDK 6

Now Travis CI does not (yet) natively support a task that uploads the created artifact after all tasks have been finished, so I am using a workaround to this.

My question is about the fact that the workaround will attempt to upload to the Sonatype snapshot repository the artifact that has been created as *last*.

This means that one time it will upload a snapshot that has been compiled by Open JDK 6, the other time by Open JDK 7, etc, etc.

Does this matter? Can a Java 6 client use Java 6 code that gets compiled by any Java 6+ JDK? We already know that the code (seemingly) does what it is intended to do, as it compiled and the tests have passed at this point.

It is intended that the Java 6 code can be run on any Java 6 compatible JRE and on Android.

Comment: You shouldn't have problems with Java 6 code compiled under JDK 8 (for example), but you could have fun trying to compile JDK 7 or 8 code in JDK6. For example, switch statements work fine in 7+, but will throw compile errors in 6.

Comment: @Dave It's all Java 6 code that I am compiling here, on any of those JDK's. I am not attempting to compile (say) Java 8 code for Java 6.

Comment: Then you should have no issue. But one day, you'll be given requirements to write in JDK7, end up using features not supported in 6, and spend half a day wondering why Travis won't compile for you. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. - but you have to specify `-target`

When Java compiles classes it compiles it for a target Java JRE. For refernce, see the [javac option for javac 1.7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html) (and [for Java8 here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html))

> ```
> -target version
>     Generate class files that target a specified version of the VM.
>     Class files will run on the specified target and on later versions,
>     but not on earlier versions of the VM.
>     Valid targets are 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5 (also 5), 1.6 (also 6), and 1.7 (also 7).
>
> The default for -target depends on the value of -source:
>
>     If -source is not specified, the value of -target is 1.7
>     If -source is 1.2, the value of -target is 1.4
>     If -source is 1.3, the value of -target is 1.4
>     If -source is 1.5, the value of -target is 1.7
>     If -source is 1.6, the value of -target is 1.7
>     For all other values of -source, the value of -target is the value of -source.
> ```

So, code compiled with Java8 javac, with a -target of 1.7, will be runnable on Java7 JRE only if the code does not use any features available in Java8 or later.

So, in your case, code compiled with your Java8 JDK, if it does not have a -target argument for the javac command, will fail to even load on Java6. The error will be: [UnsupportedClassVersionError](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/UnsupportedClassVersionError.html)

Answer (score 2):

If you build your code successfully in Java 6 and Java 8 (defining the target version), you can give your code to another person and only need them to have Java 6+ (also setting the target version) and it will work on any Java 6 or higher.

To do this you need to set the `-target 1.6 -source 1.6` or specify the version in [maven-compiler-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html). (I highly suggest you use a build tool)

In maven you would set

```
<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    [...]
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.6</source>
          <target>1.6</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
    [...]
  </build>
  [...]
</project>
```

And anyone who uses your build will create a JAR with byte code runnable on Java 6+

---

When you compile byte code for Java 6 in Java 8 it will be fine to use on Java 6+

Where you find a problem is that Java 8 has more classes and methods in the JDK compared with Java 6.  This means a Java 8 compiler will happily compile Java 6 which uses class, methods or field which are available in Java 8 but are not available in Java 6.

It is possible to tell the Java 8 compiler to use Java 6 libraries when compiling the code, but a much simpler solution is to use a Java 6 compiler, or you can assume that this won't happen or you have another means to detecting that the Java 6 code is only using libraries available to Java 6.

You could have the same problem with third party libraries.  You could be compiling against a version of a 3rd party library which works in Java 8, but for Java 6 you have to use an older version of the libraries (or perhaps none exists)

Another issue you will have is that Java 8 has fixed some bugs in the compiler which Java 6 allows. These fixes are pretty exotic and you have to have written non-standard Java code (which Java 6 allowed due to bugs in the compiler)

Javadoc will by default complain about non-stand Javadoc and even fail to build when Java 6's javadoc will pass.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot force exactly which Java compiler I'll be using, all I know it's a Java 6+ compiler. Is there a guarantee that every compiler generates the same bytecode, or is the only guarantee that it shows the same behavior?

Comment: @skiwi If you have code which builds on Java 6 and 8 you can give it to a Java 6+ user to compile and they can give it to a different Java 6+ user.

Comment: @Vogel612 Yes, I forgot some people don't use built tools or know you need to set this.

Comment: Rolfl's answer suggests that -source 1.6 marked compilations don't necessarily compile to -target 1.6. The most important thing here is the `target`-versions

Comment: @Vogel612 Correct however, the JDKs mentioned by the OP require the `-source` to be the same, though in theory another JDK compiler could be more flexible.

Comment: @PeterLawrey my Oracle JDK 7 happiliy compiled with `-source 1.6 -target 1.7` ...

Comment: @Vogel612 interesting. the only other combination I have seen is 1.0/1.1